# Solow Model - criticism of Harrod model

Tags: macroeconomics, solow

I have started out reading seminal paper of Solow - Solow Growth model. It starts out with discussing weaknesses in Harrod Domar Model, a simple model of economic growth which featured prior to solow's work. You can read about Harrod model here

https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/sanaasaluja.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/the-harrod-domar-model-of-economic-growth/amp/

While discussing about Harrod Domar Model, Solow said it consistently uses short run tools for long run analysis (see the picture). But I don't understand why he called 'the multiplier' as a short run tool and 'margin(al) [product]' as a long run tool?

[image: picture]

Comment: the multiplier is the capital coefficient?